# Spark SQL Java - Unable to create nested Row object

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is the final schema that I'm trying to achieve using Spark SQL

```
|-- references: array (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    |-- name: string (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    |-- type: string (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm trying to insert the data in Parquet however I'm unable to create a nested JSON Row object matching the above schema.

Here are the following things that I've tried and doesn't work -

```
Tried inserting the data as - Object[] references = new Object[]{"1", "2", "3"}

Tried this Object[] references - new Object[0] (Only this works)

Tried this Object[] references - new Object[]{new Object[]{"1", "2", "3"}}
```

And then i return it as

```
Row.createFactory(references)
```

Where I try to return as Row object

I require help creating the schema using Spark SQL Java. I'm unable to find any solutions online.

Comment: You need an object with name, type, url fields first. Then make an array (or list) of that. Not clear why you're trying to make a Row instead of a dataframe, though

Comment: @cricket_007 - Thanks for the response. The reference object is an array of elements i.e JSON Array. Also, I'm trying to create a dataset of Row.

Comment: A dataset of rows is just a dataframe. And you can build a dataframe from a list of predefined JSON objects. An `Object[]` does not have any schema associated with it and is not JSON. You need a `public class Element {}` with the three fields mentioned in the schema. JSON is just an implementation detail, and could be any other format, but Spark needs the class to represent that data as a Structured entity

Answer (score 1):

Look like list of arrays is available, functions "array" and "struct" can be used for create desired schema:

```
    List<Row> data = Lists.newArrayList(
            RowFactory.create(new String[]{"1", "2", "3"}),
            RowFactory.create(new String[]{"4", "5", "6"})
    );

    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(
            new StructField[]{
                    DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                    DataTypes.createStructField("type", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                    DataTypes.createStructField("url", DataTypes.StringType, true),
            });
    Dataset<Row> plain = spark().createDataFrame(data, schema);

    Dataset<Row> result = plain.withColumn("references",
            array(
                    struct(col("name"), col("type"), col("url")))).
            select("references");
    result.show(false);
    result.printSchema();
```

Output is:

```
+----------+
|references|
+----------+
|[[1,2,3]] |
|[[4,5,6]] |
+----------+

root
 |-- references: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
```